# Getting error Get object access denied when reading from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i  am trying to stream the guardduty logs from s3 to ElasticSearch.Guardduty puts the logs in the formate of .jsonl.gz

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json
import datetime
import gzip
import urllib
import urllib3
import logging
from pprint import pprint
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import requests
from io import BytesIO

"""
Can Override the global variables using Lambda Environment Parameters
"""
globalVars  = {}
globalVars['Owner']                 = "*****"
globalVars['Environment']           = "test"
globalVars['awsRegion']             = "us-east-1"
globalVars['tagName']               = "serverless-s3-to-es-log-ingester"
globalVars['service']               = "es"
globalVars['esIndexPrefix']         = "guarddutylogs-"
globalVars['esIndexDocType']        = "gdutylogsdocs"
globalVars['esHosts']               = {
                                        'test': 'https://********************.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' , 
                                        'prod': ''
                                        }

# Initialize Logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def indexDocElement(es_Url, awsauth, docData):
    try:
        headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        #headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        resp = requests.post(es_Url, auth=awsauth, headers=headers, json=docData)
        if resp.status_code == 201:
            logger.info('INFO: Successfully inserted element into ES')
        else:
            logger.error('FAILURE: Unable to index element')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('ERROR: {0}'.format( str(e) ) )
        logger.error('ERROR: Unable to index line:"{0}"'.format( str( docData['content'] ) ) )
        print (e)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
    awsauth = AWS4Auth( credentials.access_key, 
                        credentials.secret_key, 
                        globalVars['awsRegion'], 
                        globalVars['service'], 
                        session_token=credentials.token
                    )

    logger.info("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    try:    
        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        print('Bucket:' + bucket)
        key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
        print('Key:' + str(key))
        # Get documet (obj) form S3
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('ERROR: {0}'.format( str(e) ) )
        logger.error('ERROR: Unable able to GET object:{0} from S3 Bucket:{1}. Verify object exists.'.format(key, bucket) )

    if (key.endswith('.gz')) or (key.endswith('.tar.gz')):
        mycontentzip = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())).read()
        lines = mycontentzip.decode("utf-8").replace("'", '"')
        print('unziped file')
    else:
        lines = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8").replace("'", '"')

    logger.info('SUCCESS: Retreived object from S3')

    # Split (S3 object/Log File) by lines
    lines = lines.splitlines()
    if (isinstance(lines, str)):
        lines = [lines]

    # Index each line to ES Domain
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
    indexName = globalVars['esIndexPrefix'] + date
    es_Url = globalVars['esHosts'].get('test') + '/' + indexName + '/' + globalVars['esIndexDocType']

    docData = {}
    docData['objectKey']        = str(key)
    docData['createdDate']      = str(obj['LastModified'])
    docData['content_type']     = str(obj['ContentType'])
    docData['content_length']   = str(obj['ContentLength'])

    for line in lines:
        docData['content'] = str(line)
        docData['content'] = json.loads(docData['content'] )
        indexDocElement(es_Url, awsauth, docData )
    logger.info('SUCCESS: Successfully indexed the entire doc into ES')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler(None, None)
```

Here is my output:

```
ERROR: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
ERROR: Unable able to GET object:AWSLogs/<Account ID>/GuardDuty/eu-west-2/2020/02/27/b60d8505-5d06-3c75-b4f6-e62cbe01094b.jsonl.gz
```

**Lambda IAM policy has:**
S3 policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket name>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket name>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lambda Execution role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then Elasticsearch and VPCFull access.

**S3 bucket policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [


    {
            "Sid": "Allow GuardDuty to use the getBucketLocation operation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "guardduty.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "<Given s3 bucket ARN>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow GuardDuty to upload objects to the bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "guardduty.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "<Given s3 bucket ARN>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                **"AWS": "<Given Lambda  ARN>/*"** --> *added this.Getting invalid policy as result*
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "<Given s3 bucket ARN>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Kindly help me out with this error tried many ways but not sure whats the problem is

Comment: Have you tried to add `s3:GetObject` permission in your S3 bucket policy?

Comment: The last permission where you've mentioned the lambda role ARN, did you try giving lambda ARN instead of the lambda role ARN?

Comment: Hi nachary, thanks for you response, will try giving the lambda ARN.but my lambda has a full permission to the particular S3 bucket which i am referring, does that satisy the need ?

Comment: i tried with giving the lambda arn it says invalid policy

Comment: Okay can you show me what policy you've added? Also, could you show the Lambda Access Policy?

Comment: Hi nachary i have updated my post.Kindly look for the Lambda Role and S3 bucket policy i have added.

Comment: I think you should add AWS managed policy - `AWSLambdaExecute` to your role and try again. Do change your lambda ARN in bucket policy back to lambda role ARN

Comment: yes,its a aws managed lambda execute role only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .The problem was my .gz files were encrypted using the KMS key and stored in the s3 bucket.so my lambda dint have enough permission to decrypt. To solve 
it  i had to add the lambda role arn to the KMS key policy to allow the lambda to decrypt and continue with the process.

Here is my key policy before:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:<***>"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow GuardDuty to use the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "guardduty.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "kms:GenerateDataKey",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:user/****"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                **"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*******:role/<rolename>" // lambda role ARN**
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*********:user/<******>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```